# Unbound variable error when installing ffmpeg on openshift online

Tags: ffmpeg, openshift

I followed the steps on https://forums.openshift.com/ffmpeg but when performing `make install` I got this error:

```
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg.1
INSTALL doc/ffprobe.1
INSTALL doc/ffserver.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffprobe-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffserver-all.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-utils.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-scaler.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-resampler.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-codecs.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-formats.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-protocols.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-devices.1
INSTALL doc/ffmpeg-filters.1
INSTALL doc/libavutil.3
INSTALL doc/libswscale.3
INSTALL doc/libswresample.3
INSTALL doc/libavcodec.3
INSTALL doc/libavformat.3
INSTALL doc/libavdevice.3
INSTALL doc/libavfilter.3
/var/lib/openshift//python//bin/install: line 10: version: unbound variable
make: *** [install-man] Error 1
```

And It's the install file(which gives error):

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

case "$1" in
     -v|--version)
     version="$2"
esac

echo "$version" > ${OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR}env/OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_VERSION

mkdir -p ${OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR}template

# Call the version specific install script
exec ${OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR}usr/versions/${version}/bin/install $version
```

So what is the problem ? And how can I solve it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/lib/openshift//python//bin/install` is the `bin/install` script from the OpenShift [Python cartridge](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/ba298a8e916d7eb47a7e9383e43b25bd3c9a39d6/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-python/bin/install), so I'm very confused why it's getting called from `make install`.

Are you using a Python cartridge? I suspect `make` could be incorrectly resolving the standard [`install`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/install) command to your Python cartridge due to a bad PATH variable. In your OpenShift environment try

```
which install
```

and if you get anything other than `/usr/bin/install` then that's the problem. If you get the correct path here, then maybe the PATH when `make` calls `install` is messed up. Try to print the PATH at that point in the Makefile to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was (as you mentioned) the python cartridge had reserved "install" command. Removing it from "$PATH" solved it.

Answer (score 1):

When i tried to compile FFMPEG from Source Code, I faced insufficient space issue in the gear. However, using the binary from the url "https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/" works in openshift without any issue.

I am using the git based binary of 3.1.3 version and its working fine for me.

Hope this helps...